# What is the point of installing applications in default paths without consolidating the user?

Tags: linux, installation

I've been installing MySQL on a server recently and I had to edit many files and change ownerships only move the data files from their default location to some other partition.

Why is it different from installing it on Windows for instance ? Specifying MySQL data files is a very reasonable need and the same goes for another applications.

It's very annoying and I need to know why I'll always have to deal with this !

Comment: Try using symlinks instead of moving things away from where they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the Linux way.

The package manager installs all packages. It is essential to do this in order to easily upgrade and remove packages and keep track of dependencies. No package manager uses installer of a specific software package. While configuring packages sometimes users are asked question. But mostly these questions are aimed for understanding desired behavior by the user, or for learning essential information for package to work correctly.

Beyond this, the goal is always to install a package with minimum configuration and providing that a normal user does it without any effort. Linux package managers never ask users questions on non-standard behavior (like storing MySQL data files in a custom directory). If you are willing to do some specific stuff you should go into configuration files.

You might feel that the effort for configuration is too high. But be assured that mostly it is not, and the benefit of simplicity is a worthy gift.

Answer (score 3):

Because Linux has the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) and Windows does not. A place for everything, and everything in its place.

Comment: I understand that Linux has a FHS and AFAIK even each distribution adds it's own touch. But won't it allow me to relocate MySQL data files for example ? I'm not discussing MySQL in specific, I'm just giving an example. Some applications **needs** to be configured **while** installation to serve the user's requirements.

Comment: @Muhammad: This question was already verging on NaRQ; adding that bit pushes it clean over.

Comment: NaRQ ? And I really tried to find an answer before posting it here but all I mainly found was "Where is ** installed" or "How to find the installation path for **"